# How to disable extension manager updates notification

Tags: gnome

I'm working on setting up a system in kiosk mode, recently upon booting up one of the test systems here, this below picture showed.  We do not connect a mouse or keyboard, so cannot clear this when deployed.  I connected a keyboard/mouse on the test system and just moving the mouse made the notification finally go away.

Some timeout isn't triggered until the mouse moves, but on a mouse-less kiosk that auto-boots, that won't happen, so this shows indefinitely.

Looking for some way to disable this.  We have the 'gnome-extensions' manager installed.

Prefer the solution to be done via gsettings set command.  What schema and key would allow to disable this?

If cannot be done via gsettings, what file needs to be modified or permissions changed to prevent the system from checking for updates, but still allow extensions to work on the system.

Even worst case, I guess I can setup a delayed desktop script to move the mouse after a minute or so.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Check whether your distro package extensions (Debian and Fedora do) and install extensions system-wide. [Currently](https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/3.12/extensions-mandatory.html.en) they are installed in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` directory but immutable distros don't allow the user to manually move files there.
2. Install [Disable Gnome Extension Update Check](https://gitlab.com/thjderjktyrjkt/disable-gnome-extension-update-check)
3. Please look at the [gnome-shell issue #2514](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2514) for alternative workarounds (version bump, directory lock, code editing etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was able to install this extension as part of our setup process and seems to work well.  But in addition to that, we enabled "do not disturb" mode for notifications as to prevent any other nag pop-ups to show in the future.  The command we used is: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false` and also just for the heck of it, although lock screen should never show `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-in-lock-screen false`.  I will be accepting your answer.